# Using Android Navigation Component, how to make actionBar transparent and make layout full screen in single Fragment?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, fullscreen, android-navigation

> I am using Google's recommended single activity pattern with Android Jetpack's Navigation component.

I am trying to achieve [this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPtBm.jpg). I want to make the actionBar (and also the statusBar, if possible) transparent in a single Fragment. I also need to make the camera view in my XML layout fill the whole screen, so the actionBar (and maybe statusBar) is on top of it.

I have tried things such as `supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))` and `.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)` among other hacks, but none seem to work properly. Either they do nothing at all, move the actionBar on top of the statusBar, or other undesired effects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me everytime i've needed a transparent action bar:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This code seems to work best if using activities rather than Androidx Navigation Component / Fragments. I tried applying it on my Fragment, and got the **"requestFeature() must be called before adding content"** error. Then I tried to apply it in my MainActivity, which had no effect.

Comment: Ohh ok makes sense. I'll look into it and see if i can figure out the solution to your problem. Sorry that that didn't work. So are you trying to make a fragment transparent?
Have you tried setting it's background color transparent in the fragment's xml?
Also are you using a navigation view?

Comment: Also have you tried playing around with the alpha value of the background color?